# Sqlite not returning any data

Tags: sql, node.js, database, sqlite, express

I am trying to query for a specific row but anything is being returned. I made sure I have data.

I am using express.js and wrote a request where I'm sending an email value as the query value. For the sql query, when I want to return all rows, it works. But when I try to query a specific row using the WHERE clause, nothing returns.

First, this creates the users table:

```
const creatUsersTableStmt =
    `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                 firstName TEXT NOT NULL, 
                 lastName TEXT NOT NULL, 
                 email TEXT NOT NULL, 
                 phone TEXT NOT NULL,
                 UNIQUE(email)
     )`;
```

This is the sql query:

```
const fetchUser = `SELECT rowid, * FROM users WHERE email = ?`;
```

This is the route:

```
router.get('/user', function (req, res, next) {
    let userEmail = req.query.email;

    db.run(fetchUser, [userEmail], (err, user) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err.message);
        res.send(user)
    })
})
```

After creating an user with the email "rr". This is my API call:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/users/user?email="rr"
```

The response is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked it out, I changed db.run to db.all.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the double quotes from the `email` query parameter:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/user?email=rr
```

This would find all records where the literal email is `rr` (you were searching for `"rr"`).  It's doubtful that there would be any such records.  If you wanted to another email address, then use something like:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/user?email=jon.skeet@google.com
```

Comment: Just tried it and it still doesn't return anything.

Comment: Can you verify that your Node application can in fact receive the email query parameter correctly?

Comment: Yep, I console.logged it out and it prints the correct email.

Comment: Is there any error message in `err`?  I can't get `rowid` to work properly, at least not on SQLite 3.27 ([see here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=78adfd7010a1c5a671b55b09704d401b)).

Comment: No errors in the console. rowid works for me because I have another api call which fetches all rows instead of a specific row. I use sqlite3 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

use this instead.

```
   router.get('/user', function (req, res, next) {
        let userEmail = req.query.email;

        db.run(fetchUser, [userEmail], function (err, user) => {
            if (err) return console.log(err.message);
            res.send(user)
        })
    })
```

Comment: I'm not sending id as a query string though. I'm sending email because I'm trying to get the id, hence the rowid